# Disconnect a Terminal Server session… is it even possible?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, control-panel, terminal-services

I am trying to disconnect a remote terminal server session. I wonder if I even have the administrative privileges to do so. Using this description: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785968(v=ws.10).aspx I have gone to the Control Panel but I do not find the Terminal Services Manager. Is it named something else? When I type it in the start menu I find and run some soft of System Properties window. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `Remote Desktop Services Manager` which is found under `Administrative Tools`, not in the Control Panel.  Windows servers have the Administrative Tools by default, or you can download the tools from Microsoft.  [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) is the Win7 version.  You do need administrative access to the server to perform actions like disconnected RDC sessions.